# Can't add an item into recycler view from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

Hi i have already looked into some posts about this, and tried all of what people have been answering but i haven't got any luck.

What i'm trying to do, is that the user touch a floating button and go to another activity, where the user has to enter a name and number of visits in order to add another card view with that info. I have tried all of the notifydatasetchanged(), notifyitemsinserted() but i haven't got any luck.

What i have done is this:

```
 private RecyclerView recycler;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;
List<Anime> items = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Inicializar Animes


    items.add(new Anime(R.drawable.angel, "Angel Beats", 230));
    items.add(new Anime(R.drawable.death, "Death Note", 456));
    items.add(new Anime(R.drawable.fate, "Fate Stay Night", 342));
    items.add(new Anime(R.drawable.nhk, "Welcome to the NHK", 645));
    items.add(new Anime(R.drawable.suzumiya, "Suzumiya Haruhi", 459));

    // Obtener el Recycler
    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
    lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);

    // Crear un nuevo adaptador
    adapter = new AnimeAdapter(items);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void agregar (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this ,AgregarActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void agregarItem(Anime anime){
    items.add(anime);
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size() -1);
}
```

My Adapter

```
public class AnimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimeAdapter.AnimeViewHolder> {

private List<Anime> items;

public static class AnimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Campos respectivos de un item
    public ImageView imagen;
    public TextView nombre;
    public TextView visitas;

    public AnimeViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        visitas = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.visitas);
        ((ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.detalle)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), AgregarActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nom", nombre.getText().toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

public AnimeAdapter(List<Anime> items) {
    this.items = items;
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public AnimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.anime_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new AnimeViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AnimeViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(items.get(i).getImagen());
    viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(i).getNombre());
    viewHolder.visitas.setText("Visitas:" + items.get(i).getVisitas());

}

public void agregarItem(Anime anim){
    items.add(anim);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and my other activity

```
 MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
public void agregar(View view) {
    EditText nom = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNombre));
    EditText vis = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etVisitas));
    Anime anime = new Anime(R.drawable.house, nom.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(vis.getText().toString()));
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    activity.agregarItem(anime);
}
```

SOLVED:

What i did was to instead of using startActivity on mainActivity, i used startActivityForResult and then returning the data and processing it using an override method onActivityResult

Comment: You are changing Activity collection, but have to change adapter collection - public void agregarItem(Anime anime){
    items.agregarItem(anime);
} - inside activity

Comment: I think that i didn't understand, in my adapter class i have the agregarItem() method that receives an object and it adds to the adapter arrayList and notifies it. But on the normal activity that i execute the change i can't instatiate AnimeAdapter because i have to pass a list through the constructor.

Comment: You have agregarItem(Anime anime) function both in Activity and adapter. Wheb you call activity.agregarItem(anime); you add item to activity's collection, and adapter doesn't know about it collection, cause adpater has it's own. Did you try my code

Comment: I got confused because i named them the same haha but i got it. Already tried it, no errors but my recycler view in MainActivity didn't changed. I did this:   https://pastebin.com/qJ8PxDe3

Comment: what do you mean by *MainActivity main = new MainActivity()* . are you creating activity instance?

Comment: I created it because the only way to access agregarItem(Anime anime) method in the MainActivity class or make the methods and variables in MainActivity static

Comment: in that case you should make agregarItem() static and call it

Comment: Already did it, but no luck. You can see what i did in the pastebin up the comments.

Comment: a better way to pass nom and vis data to previous activity is through intent i think you should call notify on adapter when activity is in foreground so just get data from intent and push it to list